# transformar uma coluna integer em factor dentro de um data.frame no R

Tags: r

Queria saber o comando para conseguir transformar uma coluna que é de números inteiros no R em factor estando dentro de um data frame.

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Utilize `data$col <- as.factor(data$col)`

Answer (score 0):

Conforme comentado pelo @Daniel Ikenaga a solução passa por utilizar a função `as.factor()`.

Segue um exemplo reprodutível:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             aluno = c("Roberto", "Paulo", "Jéssica", "Nara"),
              nota = c(3L, 6L, 7L, 10L)
)

> df
    aluno nota
1 Roberto    3
2   Paulo    6
3 Jéssica    7
4    Nara   10
```

Como se pode ver, a coluna "nota" está como "integer":

```
glimpse(df)

Rows: 4
Columns: 2
$ aluno <chr> "Roberto", "Paulo", "Jéssica", "Nara"
$ nota  <int> 3, 6, 7, 10
>
```

Usando a função `as.factor()`:

```
df_fct <- df %>% 
  mutate(nota_fct = as.factor(nota))

    aluno nota nota_fct
1 Roberto    3        3
2   Paulo    6        6
3 Jéssica    7        7
4    Nara   10       10
```

Conferindo com `glimpse()`:

```
glimpse(df_fct)
Rows: 4
Columns: 3
$ aluno    <chr> "Roberto", "Paulo", "Jéssica", "Nara"
$ nota     <int> 3, 6, 7, 10
$ nota_fct <fct> 3, 6, 7, 10
>
```